# Javascript ParseFloat to autofill without decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I have some inputs in a HTML form using javascript to autofill the inputs on changes

The problem is that the follow code show decimals longer decimals like this 42880.34623465464356435634 The code is:

```
thetotal.value = parseFloat(total.value) * (1.00/1.19);
```

This code get the price less taxes from the total and it works, but it show me the decimals...

What I need is the price to be in the example:

```
42880
```

Without dots or commas . or , like 42.880 or 42,880 and absolutly not 42880.34623465464356435634

I only want to show 42880

Tried with .round like this:

```
thetotal.value = parseFloat(total.value) * (1.00/1.19).round(2);
```

.round(2) but for some reason the addEventListener stop working for this input when using .round(2)

Comment: So you want `parseInt()`?!...

Comment: What is wrong with `parseInt()`?!

Comment: it is working perfect thanks a lot

Comment: How to calculate the 19% taxes here ? totaltaxes.value = parseInt(parseFloat(totaltopay.value) / (1.19 * 0.19));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user parseInt function for it. Like below :

```
thetotal.value = parseInt(parseFloat(total.value) * (1.00/1.19));
```

You will get only Integer as output.

Another way is Math.round. Like it below :

```
thetotal.value = Math.round(parseFloat(total.value) * (1.00/1.19));
```

Comment: Another way to do it ?

Comment: Math.round function of javascript.

Comment: Benefit of Math.round function is
1) 4280.51678 will be converted in to 4281
2) 4280.41678 will be converted in to 4280

If decimal value is 0.50 or greater then 1 will be added up like 4280 has been converted in to 4281 and if value is 0.49 or less than it then one will not added and value will be 4280.

Comment: How to calculate the 19% taxes here ? totaltaxes.value = parseInt(parseFloat(totaltopay.value) / (1.19 * 0.19));

Comment: @Liberator 19% tax of totaltopay.value?

Comment: Yes exactly of the total we get the 19% of taxes example if price total to pay is 1000 the taxes must be 160

Comment: 19% of 1000 should be 190 I guess. Or anything else is remaining in calculation?

Comment: No, because 840 + 19% is 1000 so 1000 less 840 the taxes are 160

Comment: Please use this formula : parseInt((parseFloat(totaltopay.value)*19)/100);

Comment: @Liberator So your formula is like TotalAmount = Amount + 19% of Amount. Right? So which value you will have? Will you have Amount and based on it you have to calculate TotalAmount?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use `Math.round()`?

```js
var total = {};
total.value = 51027.6120192;
var thetotal = {};

thetotal.value = Math.round(parseFloat(total.value) * (1.00/1.19));

document.write(thetotal.value);
```

**Output**

```
42880
```